# Checking if date is before another date in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, triggers

I'm still working on my university tasks and here I have to create trigger on table

```
MARRIAGE(ID_marriage, Date_of_wedding, Date_of_divorce);
```

which would work on UPDATE statement so that if someone tries to add or edit date_of_divorce it would make sure that it is AFTER date_of_wedding.

Here's how example of data looks:

```
ID_marriage  | Date_of_wedding  |  Date_of_divorce
1             39/04/12             39/04/12
2             71/04/12             null
```

Now my question is how do I compare such dates in PL/SQL?

Comment: No need for a trigger, a check constraint will work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Perfectly agreed. Better you can post the syntax as an answer. (Its your answer :))

Comment: It's university task so I kinda have to create trigger, doubt that they would be happy with my writing check constraints instead. Anyway if you have spare time you can post syntax so that I can learn something new :D Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a trigger, a check constraint will work do:

```
alter table marriage
   add constraint check_divorce
   check (date_of_divorce is null or date_of_divorce > date_of_wedding);
```

As for the trigger, you need to compare the values of `new.date_of_divorce` and `new.date_of_wedding` - essentially the same condition as I have used in the check constraint. If the `date_of_divorce` is bigger you need to raise an exception to abort the insert or update statement.

As this is a school project, I won't give you the full code, you should find the correct syntax on your own.

The relevant chapters in the manual are:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00705
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS781